# Can we get target name (executable) in clang checker?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, clang-static-analyzer

I know [SourceManager](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html) can give us the file name. Assuming, I have a CMake based project having subprojects, and the checker is invoked using

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker debug.SomeCustomChecker make
```

I am wondering whether I can get the name of the target for which the checker is being called right now. And if possible the name of the project as well. The most I am able to get so far is the file name ([SourceManager::getFilename](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a1b7402699ef496ecc9b2db28a83f0c1b)), but not the target or the project.

Thank You

Comment: I heard about some preprocessor macro called `__FILE__` which contains the name of the translation unit.  Would this help?

Comment: I have tried using that, It ends up giving me the name of my checker's source file. Whereas the SourceManager API I have mentioned actually gives the name of the file being compiled. I want the name of the executable that will be generated after compiling the said file.